# Como recorro este objeto con javascript o con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[[{"idParticipante":10,"nombre":"Arnold","sumaCorrectas":4},
{"idParticipante":15,"nombre":"Wozniak","sumaCorrectas":3},
{"idParticipante":16,"nombre":"Connor Mcgregor","sumaCorrectas":2},
{"idParticipante":12,"nombre":"Steve Jobs","sumaCorrectas":2},
{"idParticipante":13,"nombre":"Jhony Gabriel","sumaCorrectas":1},
{"idParticipante":11,"nombre":"Charly Custom","sumaCorrectas":1},
{"idParticipante":14,"nombre":"Cambray","sumaCorrectas":1},    
{"idParticipante":17,"nombre":"Carles Puyo","sumaCorrectas":0}],{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":34,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}]
```

Quiero obtener el valor de nombre y sumaCorrectas pero no lo he logrado he usado la función $.each de jquery pero no me funciona, denme sus sugerencias por favor.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar el método `map` sin necesidad de recurrir a jQuery:

```js
var foo = [
  [
    {"idParticipante":10,"nombre":"Arnold","sumaCorrectas":4},
    {"idParticipante":15,"nombre":"Wozniak","sumaCorrectas":3},
    {"idParticipante":16,"nombre":"Connor Mcgregor","sumaCorrectas":2},
    {"idParticipante":12,"nombre":"Steve Jobs","sumaCorrectas":2},
    {"idParticipante":13,"nombre":"Jhony Gabriel","sumaCorrectas":1},
    {"idParticipante":11,"nombre":"Charly Custom","sumaCorrectas":1},
    {"idParticipante":14,"nombre":"Cambray","sumaCorrectas":1},    
    {"idParticipante":17,"nombre":"Carles Puyo","sumaCorrectas":0}
  ],
  {
      "fieldCount":0,
      "affectedRows":0,
      "insertId":0,
      "serverStatus":34,
      "warningCount":0,
      "message":"",
      "protocol41":true,
      "changedRows":0
    }
];
var result = foo[0].map(function(el) { return {nombre: el.nombre, sumaCorrectas: el.sumaCorrectas}; });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Muchas esto ha funcionado

Answer (score 1):

Te falto especificar en el `$each` primero a la posición `foo[0]`, una vez hecho eso en la parte de `value` ya puedes acceder a cada propiedad `nombre` y `sumaCorrectas`

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var foo = [
  [
    {"idParticipante":10,"nombre":"Arnold","sumaCorrectas":4},
    {"idParticipante":15,"nombre":"Wozniak","sumaCorrectas":3},
    {"idParticipante":16,"nombre":"Connor Mcgregor","sumaCorrectas":2},
    {"idParticipante":12,"nombre":"Steve Jobs","sumaCorrectas":2},
    {"idParticipante":13,"nombre":"Jhony Gabriel","sumaCorrectas":1},
    {"idParticipante":11,"nombre":"Charly Custom","sumaCorrectas":1},
    {"idParticipante":14,"nombre":"Cambray","sumaCorrectas":1},    
    {"idParticipante":17,"nombre":"Carles Puyo","sumaCorrectas":0}
  ],
  {
      "fieldCount":0,
      "affectedRows":0,
      "insertId":0,
      "serverStatus":34,
      "warningCount":0,
      "message":"",
      "protocol41":true,
      "changedRows":0
    }
];

$.each( foo[0], function( key, value ) {
  console.log( "Nombre: " + value.nombre + " Sumas Correctas: " + value.sumaCorrectas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Esto funciono para mi muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro @EduardoBarrios, Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor considera aceptarla haciendo click en el ✔️ a la izquierda.